# How to uncheckall the checkboxes on the check of one checkbox using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having three checkboxes as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Orange" ng-model="selectMe1">Orange
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Pink" ng-model="selectMe2">Pink
```

and one more checkbox to clear all checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="none" ng-model="clearMe">None
```

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="none" ng-click="clearAll()" ng-model="clearMe">
```

Javascript code

```
 $scope.clearAll=function(){
     $scope.selectMe1=false;
     $scope.selectMe2=false;

 }
```

Comment: This is working, Thank you, one more thing i would like to ask, what can we do to disable unchecked  checkboxes.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled=”disabledMe1” ng-true-value="Orange" ng-model="selectMe1">Orange
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled=”disabledMe2”  ng-true-value="Pink" ng-model="selectMe2">Pink
and add $scope.disableMe1=false and $scope.disableMe2=false;

Answer (score 0):

These links might be helpfull  for you:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-checked.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-checked

Answer (score 0):

A `toggle` function in `ng-click` should help you. Try this.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="0" ng-model="clearMe" ng-click="toggle()">None
```

In your controller, you can add

```
$scope.toggle = function()
{
    $scope.selectMe1 = 'false';
    $scope.selectMe2 = 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample that can help you :

**Html**

```
 <div>
    <ul ng-controller="checkboxController">
        <li>Check All
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Items">
            <label>{{item.Name}}
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    angular.module("CheckAllModule", [])
    .controller("checkboxController", function checkboxController($scope) {


    $scope.Items = [{
        Name: "Item one"
    }, {
        Name: "Item two"
    }, {
        Name: "Item three"
    }];
    $scope.checkAll = function () {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
            item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
        });

    };


});
```

[this a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aitnasser/y2uy3vpf/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your last checkbox `ng-change=disableall()` into  your last checkbox,

**on your controller:**

```
$scope.selectMe1 = false;//init
$scope.selectMe2 = false;//init
$scope.clearMe = false;//init

$scope.disableall() = function(){
    //let's say that you clear when the checkbox is true
     if($scope.clearMe){
           $scope.selectMe1 = false;
           $scope.selectMe2 = false;        
     }
}
```

Hope helps ,good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectMe1">Orange
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectMe2">Pink

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="clearMe" ng-click="selectMe1=selectMe2=0;">None
```

Comment: when i am trying to use code on ng-click, and setting the value to flase but my ng-value and ng-model are like qualitative.question28.options.option1_CHECKBOX, angular is not accepting this notation

Answer (score 0):

```
try this,
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">    </script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<form id="selectionForm">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAll()" >Select all
    <br>
     <div ng-repeat = "option in options">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.selected" ng-change="optionToggled()">{{option.value}}
     </div>
</form>
  {{options}} 
</div>

<script>
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){

  $scope.options = [
    {value:'Option1', selected:true}, 
    {value:'Option2', selected:false}
  ];

  $scope.toggleAll = function() {
     var toggleStatus = false;
     angular.forEach($scope.options, function(itm){ itm.selected = toggleStatus; });

  }

});
</script>
```